# Is this a true inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Suppose that $x_1,x_2,...x_N$ are real vectors with the dimension of $n$. Define $X=[x_1^T,...,x_N^T]^T$. Is it true to say:
$||X||\le||x_1||+||x_2||+...+||x_N||$ where $||X||$ is the Euclidian 2-norm of the vector $X$?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
X = [x_1^T,...,x_N^T]^T = [x_1^T,0 ,..., 0 ]^T  + \ldots + [0,0,...,0,x_N^T]^T
\end{align}

By triangle inequality.

\begin{align}
\left\|X \right\|  &\le \left\|[x_1^T,0 ,..., 0 ]^T\right\|  + \ldots + \left\|[0,0,...,0,x_N^T]^T \right\| 
\\&=\sum_{i=1}^n \left\| x_i\right\|
\end{align}